# Using FILTER in Excel to return the name of the sheet the search result is in?

Tags: excel, filter

Long time listener, first timer caller.

I have a workbook with a Home tab and 20 other tabs labelled "Region X" where X is between 1-20. Each Region has a column with the names of all school districts in the region and I'm trying to make a search function on the Home tab to allow a user to find the region the desired school district is in.

I've been experimenting just with the Region 1 sheet and it's working okay. I have a search bar on K3 and the return on K6:

=FILTER('Region 1'!B2:B39,O3#,"Not Found")

My N column is =SEARCH(K3,'Region 1'!B2:B39) to accommodate partial matches in the search and the O column is =ISNUMBER(N3#)

I would like to expand the search to all the other Region tabs as well as return the name of the sheet rather than the name of the school district.

Any help would be much appreciated!

I tried doing "+ _______" to add arrays from other sheets, but it didn't work the way I intended.

Comment: Bit of a slow reply so not sure if you're still after an answer. It would help if you could attach some screenshots of the Home and a Region sheet (redacting any private information obviously!). From the details you've given, I think using VSTACK(FILTER('Region 1'!B2:B39,O3#,"Not Found"), FILTER('Region 2'!B2:B39,O3#,"Not Found"), ...) could work for expanding your search.

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for the reply.

I ended up making a reference sheet that has each district listed with its region and my search refers to that. A little inelegant, but it did the job.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.